# Centrally managed azure pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm working on an ADO project that currently has 100+ repos each of which contains the exact same pipeline which defines a schedule and points to another repo containing templates to use. Unfortunately the time has came to roll out some changes to the schedule and structure of the pipeline (before it was job templates now it is stages).

As you can imagine, I don't really want to go through 100+ repos to make changes. If I really have to, I don't want to ever do it again.

Therefore my question, is it possible to centrally manage these pipelines? i.e. I have a repo containing all the yml files then when I want to create a pipeline for a new repo I can just point to that yaml repo?

Cheers,

AP

Comment: Hi Does danielorn's solution help? If yes,  you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could help other community members who get the same issues, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `extends` construct to put the full pipeline definition inside the common repository and then just expose parameters for what must be configured per repo (if any).

From the [documentation of templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops)

> Templates let you define reusable content, logic, and parameters.
> Templates function in two ways. You can insert reusable content with a
> template or you can use a template to control what is allowed in a
> pipeline.
>
> If a template is used to include content, it functions like an include
> directive in many programming languages. Content from one file is
> inserted into another file. **When a template controls what is allowed
> in a pipeline, the template defines logic that another file must
> follow.**

It sounds like you have been using the templates like include directives up until now, by instead extending templates as described in [Security through templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/templates?view=azure-devops#use-extends-templates) you can basically put the full definition of the pipeline, including jobs and stages in the template:

> Azure Pipelines offers two kinds of templates: includes and extends.
> Included templates behave like #include in C++: it's as if you paste
> the template's code right into the outer file, which references it. To
> continue the C++ metaphor, **extends templates are more like
> inheritance: the template provides the outer structure of the pipeline
> and a set of places where the template consumer can make targeted
> alterations.**

**Example:**

```
# File: pipeline.yaml
# Repo: templaterepo
parameters:
- name: CustomProperty
  type: String

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
    steps:
      - script: echo "Custom property is ${{ parameters.CustomProperty}}"
```

```
# File: azure-pipelines.yml, placed in each of you 100 repos
# Repo: myapp

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: templaterepo

trigger:
- master

extends:
  template: pipeline.yml@templates
  parameters:
      CustomProperty: "Hello World"
```

The file inside each of the 100 repos can be mostly static if the number of configuration options are kept to a minimum. By [referencing a branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#use-other-repositories) rather that a tag in the repo containing the common pipeline (like `master`/`main` new pipelines created will always fetch the latest pipeline definition on that branch, reducing rollouts of changes in the central pipeline to just push it to the correct branch.

Comment: So could we put the schedule inside the extends template?

Comment: Good question, not sure from the top of my head if the schedule can go into the template. If not you can alwasy use variable groups to externalize the parts that change into a central location. Please see [Use a variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-variable-group) in the docs

Comment: Schedule, just like triggers, has to be duplicated in all these other pipelines yaml files.